# How to replace link with list element and then add new link in IE7/8 with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't control how the HTML is generated and need to put a string of links into a list and then add new links for each item.

I have simplified the code at http://jsfiddle.net/jhASu/ and it works in Chrome/Firefox and IE9 but not in IE 7 and 8 (no new links are generated). What could be the cause of this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does "add new links for each of them" mean?

Comment: remove the old link and add a new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/jhASu/11/

This works I would extract your function a little bit more though: This only adds the anchor to one like you wanted based on the preset value.

Comment: Thanks, what I found out is that for .wrap() to work with IE7/8 I need to add the closing tag as well. I.e. .wrap('<a></a>') not just .wrap('<a>') (also for the list)

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jhASu/2/) what you had in mind?

```
$('#div1').find('a').wrap('<ul />').each(function() {
    $(this).wrap('<li>');
});
```

Comment: No not completely, I also need to change the URL for the links. The fiddle I posted works in Firefox, Chrome and IE9, I want the same functionality to work in IE7 and 8 as well.